# iPhone:How to change default delete button's frame in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have facing problem is that Is there any way to change default frame 
of delete button in `UITableView` and one more thing is that delete button is always display in center of cell of `UITableViewcell` so any way to change frame of delete button.

```
// Update the data model according to edit actions delete or insert.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        [appDelegate.categories removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [categoryTableView reloadData];
    } 
}

#pragma mark Row reordering
// Determine whether a given row is eligible for reordering or not.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    return YES;
}

// Process the row move. This means updating the data model to correct the item indices.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath 
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath 
{
    NSString *item = [[appDelegate.categories objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row] retain];
    [appDelegate.categories removeObject:item];
    [appDelegate.categories insertObject:item atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
    [item release];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

in ios 6.1 i was not able to use the above code. I've seen several answers that suggests subclassing the cell class and providing a custom -`willTransitionToState`. Changing the subview/buttonview frame does not affectively change it's displayed position.

However if you override the `layoutSubviews` method it will work. Here is the code:

```
//below i moved the delete button to the left by 10 points. This is because my custom tableview has lef

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    for(UIView *subview in self.subviews)
    {
        if([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl"])
        {
            CGPoint o = subview.center;
            subview.center = CGPointMake(o.x - 10, o.y);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own view by setting the cell's `editingAccessoryView` property. This can have whatever frame you like, though you'll need to supply a gradient if you want it to look like the standard delete button.

In the `xib` file of your custom cell, add a new button of whatever size you like (as long as it is smaller than the cell!). This button should not be a subview of your cell, but a separate item in the file.

Connect this button to the `editingAccessoryView` outlet of your cell and it will replace the standard delete button.

Comment: please tell me tutorial or any link

Comment: Is your cell created from a xib file or is it one of the default types?

Comment: I am creating cell(CustomCell) which is a subclass of UITableViewCell

Comment: See updated answer. I don't have any links other than the apple docs.

Comment: thanks a lot but not work any way to set delete button in cell