# Increase size of delete subview in swipe to delete TableView cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am implementing a TableView menu which is accessed via a sliding view controller. The TableView is the "revealed" VC.

Users will need to delete items from the menu TableView, and I have implemented slide to delete, but my question is **how can I increase the size of the delete SubView so that it is not masked by my sliding view controller?**

I have managed a hack-y solution by implementing the

```
titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method, and added trailing spaces in the literal so that the text in the delete SubView is not hidden, but there must be a more elegant way to address this. Is there a way to increase the size?

Here's a screenshot of the interim solution in action:

[image: TableView with kludgy delete fix]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    for(UIView *subview in self.subviews)
    {
        if([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationControl"])
        {
            CGFrame oldFrame = subview.bonds.frame;
            subview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

[iPhone:How to change default delete button's frame in UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606276/iphonehow-to-change-default-delete-buttons-frame-in-uitableviewcell)